# Redirect entire directory with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I can't figure out why my redirects aren't working as they are in another htaccess file.

I'm trying to redirect old urls to new ones.

---

```
RewriteEngine on
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
<IfModule mod_php.c>
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Redirect /private_3 http://website.com/new_private
```

---

I've tried all sorts of things that I've found on the web but nothing works.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Which URL is not redirecting?

Comment: When asking a question, please always be very clear *what doesn't work*. "nothing works" is never a good problem description. In this case: Do you get an error? Do you get a white screen? Is the browser not redirected? Is it redirected to the wrong url? It will also be helpful to list what urls you tried and what the outcome was when entering these urls, where this `.htaccess` is located (relative to the www-root of your website) and if you tested if mod_rewrite is actually enabled (does `RewriteRule ^foo$ /bar [R,L]` redirect you?). What is this other .htaccess file you talk about?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this:

```
Redirect /private_3 http://website.com/new_private
```

Try adding this *right below the `RewriteEngine on` line*:

```
RewriteRule ^private_3(.*)$ http://website.com/new_private$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks bad ordering and mixing of `mod_alias` with `mod_rewrite` might be a problem here. Try reordering your rules as this:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
<IfModule mod_php.c>
   php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^private_3 http://website.com/new_private [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(system.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1
```